# How to connect to a MongoDb of a docker container

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I've created the following docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"
services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo:latest
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: admin
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: admin
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'
```

I then start my containers:

```
docker-compose up
```

then I try to connect into MongoDb Compass(also tried through c# code), with the following:

- mongodb://admin:admin@localhost:27017/?authSource=admin
- mongodb://admin:admin@localhost:27017
- mongodb://admin:admin@127.0.0.1:27017

But I always get a "Authentication failed" message:

[image]

I really don't understand what is going on. What am I missing.

Sorry for the dumb question...

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a problem with docker or with your docker-compose configuration. If I use your `docker-compose.yaml` verbatim, I can connect to it using the Python client using the URL `mongodb://admin:admin@localhost:27017`.

Comment: @larsks any idea what else could it be? Or how to get more logs?

Comment: Any chance that you have a second mongodb instance already running on your system? With your docker container stopped, is anything listening on port 27017?

Comment: @larsks Dude, you're a life-saver. I've no idea when I did install it, but I found the service, stopped it, and now I can connect. You should post this comment as answer for me to accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you're seeing suggests that there is already another  mongodb instance running on your system (with different authentication credentials). Stop the Docker container and check to see if there is still a mongodb service listening on port 27017.

Comment: In my case, it wasn't another docker image with mongo, but directly mongo installed locally

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be better to set ports to

```yaml
ports:
   - '27012:27017'
```

So you don't need to delete anything from your system.
Now you can connect as ussual, just change port to `27012` instead of `27017`

Also this way you can run multiple monogdb's using more ports wthout any issues. In my case I still needed local mongodb running and because of that port 27017 was automatically connecting to it.